Run command after reattaching to GNU Screen
I use GNU Screen to run programs. One of my programs sets up a custom cursor colour. When I reattach to the program via GNU Screen, the cursor does not restore to the custom colour, until I refresh the screen in the program.
I'd like to config GNU Screen to always run a refresh command after I reattach. Is this possible?

It's not very clear to me what you mean by refresh here, do you mean the redisplay screen command (as bound by default on prefix-l, prefix-^L) or a command called refresh on your system, or some specific action within some TUI software. In the latter case, how would you invoke that action? By a series of key presses, by clicking somewhere?

Terminals such as xterm support setting the cursor colour with things like printf '\e]12;blue\a', but AFAIK, GNU screen doesn't support such escapes. Do you have some configuration in place for screen to let those escape sequences through from applications to the host terminal?

@StéphaneChazelas GNU Screen does make it a bit tricky, but it does support it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html ; simply wrap your terminal escape code with ESC P and ESC \\, and it will work.

@StéphaneChazelas By refresh, I meant that I was hoping to call a command on the shell whenever GNU Screen reattaches.

You mean on the shell you run the screen reattaching command, or on the shell that happens to be sitting at its prompt in the current screen window, or in a new shell to be started in a new screen window, or by screen's exec command?

@StéphaneChazelas I know how to trigger my application to refresh, so it doesn't really matter where I run the command, as long as I can run it after the screen attaches.

Would something like screen -S "$the_session_you_want_to_reattach_to" -X exec sh -c 'sleep 0.5; the-cmd-you-want-to-run'; screen -xS "$the_session_you_want_to_reattach_to" work for your use case?

If it's just about changing the host terminal cursor colour, why can't you just do printf '\e]12;blue\a'; screen -xS "$the_session_you_want_to_reattach_to"?

Well it would work, but I have remember which session has which configs, and type the command myself. This would be quite inconvenient, and I would prefer to config screen to issue the command automatically.
